# String / Byte difference between Juypter and Vsc with Python

Tags: python, string, byte, word-cloud

```
from wordcloud import WordCloud, STOPWORDS
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import json
import os
import re

# Get page
param_dict = {'db': 'pubmed', 'term': 'escherichia', 'rettype': 'uilist'}
headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'}

link = "https://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/redhotchilipeppers/nottheone.html"
page = requests.get(link, params=param_dict, headers=headers)

# Lyrics
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
lyrics_area = soup.find_all('div', class_="col-xs-12 col-lg-8 text-center")
lyrics_area = lyrics_area[0].find_all('div')
lyrics = lyrics_area[5]
lyrics = soup.text.replace("\n", " ")
lyrics = lyrics.replace("|", " ")
lyrics = lyrics.split("Submit Corrections", 1)[0]
lyrics = lyrics.split("Lyrics", 1)[1]

# Title
song_title = link.rsplit('/', 1)[-1].replace(".html", "")
song_title = song_title + '.json'

cleaned_data_lyric = []
regex = re.compile('[^a-zA-Z]')
cleaned_data = lyrics.strip().split(" ")
for word in cleaned_data:
    word = regex.sub('', word)
    cleaned_data_lyric.append(word)
string = ' '.join(cleaned_data_lyric)
string = string.replace(
    "AZLyricscom                          A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z           Search                                         ", "")
string = re.sub(' +', ' ', string)

# Wordcloud
wordcloud = WordCloud(
    background_color="white",
    max_words=200,
    stopwords=set(STOPWORDS)).generate(string)
plt.imshow(wordcloud, interpolation='bilinear')
plt.axis("off")
plt.show()
```

When I run this code in VSC within the conda base then it causes an error at the wordcloud line, where variable string is not considered to be a string, however it does not cause the error in a juypter notebook.

Both are Python 3. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you show the stacktrace? What happens if you `print(type(string))` right before that line? Are you sure it's running the exact same code between jupyter and VSCode?

Comment: Yeh it's running the same code between the two. Type string in both instances shows class str, not byte

Comment: Please show the stack trace